# How to JOptionPane() after right click of and object

Tags: java, mouseevent, joptionpane, right-click

I would like to make a mouse-event that allows me to right-click on a tab, to select and delete it. How do I enable the `JOptionPane()` after the tab name is right clicked?

I haven't been able to try myself as I have no idea...

Comment: When you say " haven't been able to try myself" ... why is that? What IDE are you using?

Comment: well i have no idea where to start as I have never worked with mousevents but am busy researching now any help would be appreciated I am using netbeans

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about a `JTabbedPane` here. I don't know how to detect a right click on a tab but at least I can show you how to get notified about mouse clicks and tab changes.

To be notified if the used right clicks somewhere in the `JTabbedPane` you can use:

```
tabbedPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Clicked with right mouse button somewhere on the tabbed pane");
    }
});
```

You can also get notified as soon as the user presses or releases the mouse button. See the [API documentation for `MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html).

To be notified on a tab change you can use:

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tab changed");
    }
});
```

Maybe you can combine this somehow. An idea (although not very beautiful) would be:

1. Register that the used presses the right mouse button
2. If a `stateChanged` event occurs before (or shortly after) the mouse button is released, show your message dialog.